# Mov value on floating point register to general register

Tags: c, assembly, arm64, armv8

So I am using the instruction "fmov   x0,d3" to move the value from d3 to x0, but for some reason the value on x0 remains unchanged.
Can someone, please, tell me how to properly move a value from a floating point register to a general register?

This is my code:

```
  mov    x0,#6         //Moves the decimal 0 value to the x0 register, which is the return register 
Fadd_test_64:
  fmov   d1, #7.0      //Moves floating point value to the d1 register
  fmov   d2, #2.0
  fmov   d4, #14.0     //Moves the expected result to d4
  fadd   d3,d1,d2      //d3=d1+d2
  fcmp   d3, d4        //Compares w3 to w4
  b.ne   Fadd_error_64 //if they are different, go to Fadd_error_64
  b      Fadd_end_64   //if not, go to Fadd_end_64 
Fadd_error_64: 
  fmov   x0,d3         //Moves the value on the floating point register to the return register
Fadd_end_64:
  ret   


//Functions declaration
void mathTest_64bits(void);
UINT16 FAddition_64();
 
//Main function
 
int main(void)
{
        mathTest_64bits();
   
    return 0;
}
 
 
//Functino in C to run the assembly code
void mathTest_64bits(void)
{
  int ret;
 
  ret = FAddition_64();
  if(ret!=0)
  {
    Print(L"64-bits Floating Point  Addition test:       Failed: %d",ret);
  }
  else
  {
    Print(L"64-bits Floating Point  Addition test:       Success ");
  }
  Print(L"\n");
 }
```

Comment: The instruction is correct.  Are you sure you have debugged this correctly?

Comment: Yes. I am quite sure. It seems I can't move any value to the x0 register using fmov. I have tried several stuff. x0 is my return register. The only way I am able to change it's value is by using "mov x0,#1". I just can't copy the value of any dx register using fmov.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] so I can understand what you attempt to do.

Comment: You can [edit] your question at any time to add this [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the repy. I have just added my code to the question.
It always returns 0, but it should return the value on d3, since 7+9 is not 14

Comment: I mean, 7+2 is not 14

Comment: How do you check that 0 is returned?  When I execute your code, `x0` is set to `0x4022000000000000` which interpreted as a floating point number is `9.0` and is the number you moved there.  This appears to be what your code does.

Comment: That is strange. I have this C code to execute the assembly code
ret = Addition_64();
  if(ret!=0)
  {
    Print(L"64-bits Addition test:       Failed %d",ret);
  }
  else
  {
    Print(L"64-bits Addition test:       Success ");
  }
  Print(L"\n");

Comment: What type did you declare for `Addition_64()`.  And why didn't you post a complete [mcve] in the first place?  Unless I can compile it on my own system and get the same result as you it's not a [mcve].

Comment: If `ret` is an integer, as the `%d` would suggest, then you are only going to get the low 32 bits of `x0`, which indeed is zero.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Thanks to you I have realized my mistake. It was not on the assmbly code, but on my C application. ret is indeed an integer, but this application does not support floating point.
So my new question is: How can I in the assembly code convert it the float to int, so the x0 register can return an int?

Comment: Probably you want one of the `fcvt*` instructions instead of `fmov`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried this instruction, but it returns the following error message: "Error: operand 1 must be an SVE vector register -- `fcvt x0,d3' " So I did some research and found this instrcution "fcvtas x0,d3", however, it returns a 0. I guess it is returning just part of the value. Any idea of what I can do?

Comment: @MarlonPedersoli `fcvtas x0, d3` looks correct.  Please post a [mcve] of what you tried, including all code that is needed to produce the output you observe.  Do not leave anything out.

Comment: I think with this code you will be able to reproduce what is going on
https://pastebin.pl/view/4896fdbe

Comment: @MarlonPedersoli Your return type is again incorrect.  Try `long long int` for the 64 bit integer `x0` is.  Anyway, your example code (which you should put into your question by clicking [edit], not into an external paste bin that may go down) works correctly on my machine.  Are you sure you recompiled/assembled your program after editing it?

Comment: AArch64's standard calling conventions returns `double` in `d0`, not `x0`.  https://godbolt.org/z/xaPYca shows compiler output.  Are you using some soft-float calling convention where you return the bit-pattern in `x0`, forcing the caller to put it back into an FP register if it wants to do anything other than store it?  Also, use a debugger to single-step your results instead of just looking at output printed by a caller.  You can even single-step into the caller to see where it's looking for a return value if you aren't sure.

Comment: @fuz thank you very much. Now with the long long int, my return is correct.
Could you please explain to me why this happens? 
I am sorry for the mistakes (putting my code into an external link) I am just figuring out how stackoverflow works.

Comment: Stack Overflow works best if you make your questions self-contained.  Add all relevant details directly to your question.  Make a [mcve] if possible.  Read the [mcve] article to find out what exactly that means.  Behaviour is undefined with an incorrect return type.  Depending on what wrong type specifically you use, the C code may truncate your result or simply take it from some other place.  Always specify the correct return type.  Refer to the AAPCS document on what types are returned in what way.

Comment: Also note that your example is still incomplete as it uses type (`UINT16`) without giving their definition and non-standard library function (`Print`).  For the future, make sure to provide a [mcve] that everybody can compile and run as is on their computers without having to guess what these special functions do.  It's easiest to just use standard C types (e.g. `uint16_t`) and functions (e.g. `printf`).  Also make sure to provide the full code, including all `#include` directives.  Everything you leave out is something that could be causing your error.  Don't leave others guessing.

Comment: @fuz, thanks a lot. I will try to provide a better code next time